# Assertion Failure in go_router package: 'package:go_router/src/parser.dart': Failed assertion: line 63 pos 12: 'routeInformation.state != null'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-go-router

The error  is within the **`go_router`** package and is related to an assertion failure in the **`parser.dart`** file. The specific assertion that failed is at line 63, position 12, and it checks whether **`routeInformation.state`** is not null. The assertion is there to ensure that the state associated with a route is not null.

```
'package:go_router/src/parser.dart': Failed assertion: line 63 pos 12: 'routeInformation.state != null': is not true.
```

my AppRouts class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:quizapp/screens/home/home.dart';
import '../../screens/error/error_page.dart';
import '../../screens/splash/splash_screen.dart';
import 'app_routers.dart';

class MyAppRouts {
  GoRouter route = GoRouter(
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        name: MyAppRoutesConstent.splashScreenRoutename,
        path: '/',
        pageBuilder: (context, state) {
          return const MaterialPage(child: SplashScreen());
        },
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: MyAppRoutesConstent.homeRoutename,
        path: '/home',
        pageBuilder: (context, state) {
          return const MaterialPage(child: HomePage());
        },
      ),
    ],
    errorPageBuilder: (context, state) {
      return const MaterialPage(child: ErrorPage());
    },
  );
}
```

Im new to GoRouter package what is the problem hear i need lord splash screen as my first screen and this is my main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'project/routes/app_routers_const.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Flutter Quiz App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routeInformationParser: MyAppRouts().route.routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: MyAppRouts().route.routerDelegate,
    );
  }
}
```

i need lord splash screen as my first screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, configure the MaterialApp.router like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: MyAppRouts().route,
    );
  }
}
```

and set an initial path for splash screen:

```
GoRouter route = GoRouter(initialLocation : "/splashScreen" , ..);
```